# Comparação de String não funciona utilizando o operador igual (==)

Tags: java, condição

Estou trabalhando nesse programinha em que ao digitar a raça do animal irá dizer o som que ele emite, mas ao terminar esse código algo está dando errado de modo que aparece apenas a última condição "animal não encontrado" será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

```java
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          
    String animal;
       
        
     System.out.println("digite o animal");
       animal = sc.next();
        
        if(animal == "gato"){
           System.out.println("mia");
        }
        else{
          if(animal == "cachorro"){
           System.out.println("late");
           }
          else{
             System.out.println("animal nao encontrado");
          }
        }
       
       sc.close();
       
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

O seu problema é bem simples na verdade: você está comparando as Strings de forma errada. Você precisa utilizar um desses dois métodos para fazer a comparação: `equals()` ou `equalIgnoreCase()`.

O seu código ficaria assim:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String animal;
   
    
System.out.println("digite o animal");
animal = sc.next();
    
    if(animal.equals("gato")) {
        System.out.println("mia");
    }
    else if(animal.equals("cachorro")) {
        System.out.println("late");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("animal nao encontrado");
    }
   
sc.close();
```

Uma observação rápida! O método `equals()` vai verificar se o que você digitou é igual à String que você forneceu e vai diferenciar letras maiúsculas de minúsculas. Se você não quiser que ele faça essa diferenciação use o `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Aproveito e te deixo uma sugestão, no futuro, quando você for fazer muitas validações com condicionais, dê preferência ao switch-case, pois quando você usa muito o if-else (na minha opnião mais que 3 vezes) o seu código começa a ficar poluído.

Comment: obrigado brother, deu certinho agora , muito obrigado pelas dicas